# JS to dynamically add a list to select on input if user type {

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a text editable div box in which user can add text and personalize it by adding fields like First_Name, Last_Name etc.  I want the options to show when a user press { key.

I did the js which get fired when the user types {, and added a list with the options, but when the scripts run the whole list get added on the input box instead of providing option to select from.

Here is the text div I have and the Js code

```
<div contenteditable class="text_im" name="text_im" placeholder="Enter Text" maxlength="640"></div>
```

script:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if ($(".text_im:focus") && (e.keyCode === 219)) {
     var options = '<ul><li>{First_Name}</li><li>{Last_Name}</li> <li>{Email}</li><li>{Phone}</li></ul>';
     $(".text_im").append(options);
  }
});
```

I tried searching for any tips or tutorial , but can't find any. If you could suggest me some tutorial.

Comment: Your options var is a simple html element. So an html element - in this case a list - gets added to your dom tree. Do your want to add buttons a user can click or what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I think the feature you want to add is auto complete. I'm sure there are already plugins that provide autocomplete or suggestion drop down.

Comment: I want is , if a user is typing Hello { , it will show the fields I have and when the user clicks on any of the field , it get added to the text. For example if they select {first_name} , it will add that and the text in the input field will change to Hello {first_name}  @conste

Comment: @Lian thanks for the tip. I found this https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete

Comment: @StacyThompson: I hope that plugin works for your case. If not, you can always extend it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a library for that to get a cross-browser, modern-looking result, but the basics could work like this:

- Create the options element from a template, and give it the CSS rendering it needs to show correctly at the caret position when needed.
- Show it on keypress, when character is already in the `div` element.
- Capture mouse clicks on the options
- Hide it whenever a key is pressed or user clicks on an option
- When option selected, insert corresponding text, except for the opening `{` which is already there.

Here is some code, but please note that to make this cross-browser and good-looking (with additional features), you would need a lot more. This is just to show a basic set-up:

```js
// Create element (not in DOM yet) for tooltip
var tooltip = $('#template').clone().attr('id', 'tooltip').get(0);

function insertAtCaret(node, caretBefore = false) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(node);
    range.collapse(caretBefore);
}

$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    $(tooltip).remove(); // Hide tooltip (detach it from the DOM)
    var $div = $(".text_im"), 
        ch = String.fromCharCode(e.which); // Get typed character
    if (!$div.is(":focus") || ch !== '{') return;
    setTimeout(function () { // Delay a bit, to ensure correct caret position 
        insertAtCaret(tooltip, true); // Insert the tooltip at the caret
    }, 100);
});

$(document).on('click', '#tooltip li', function () {
    var text = $(this).text().substr(1); // The text to insert
    $(tooltip).remove(); // Hide tooltip (detach it from the DOM)
    $(".text_im").focus(); // Make sure the div has focus
    insertAtCaret(document.createTextNode(text)); // Insert the text
});
```

```css
.text_im {
    border : 1px solid;
    min-height: 40px 
}
#template { 
    display: none; 
}
#tooltip {
    position: fixed; 
    margin-top: -0.2em;
    background: #eee; 
    display: inline-block; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
#tooltip li:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable class="text_im inputor" name="text_im" placeholder="Enter Text" maxlength="640"></div>
<ul id="template"><li>{First_Name}</li><li>{Last_Name}</li> <li>{Email}</li><li>{Phone}</li></ul>
```